# Listener (C#) - Getting responses from the webhook

Tags: listener, webhooks

I hope you guys will be able to assist  me, I am trying to create a listener that gets delivery statuses of sms from the webhook then update my table with the received response.

below is how the response will look like from the webhook

POST /dlr HTTP/1.1
HOST: yourdomain.com
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: text/plain
{
"Status":"DELIVRD",
"EventId":1179504595,
"Mcc":655,
"Mnc":"01",
"MsgCount":1,
"Msisdn":"27123456789",
"Received":1530013907,
"UserReference":"5b3228ad6c8d84001a6e6707"
}

Thanks in advance

Still new in C# development therefore need guidance